# Ставится ли запятая после "в противном случае"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Грамота говорит, что синтаксические конструкции, присоединяемые союзом «в противном случае», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. Но при этом приводит примеры, где после союза запятая не ставится. Так нужно ставить запятую или нет?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**В ПРОТИВНОМ СЛУЧАЕ**
Вот что говорится об этом **союзе** в толковом словаре [**Ефремовой**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/144611/%D0%92_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5):

1. **Употребляется при соединении предложений** (во втором из которых действие или событие могло бы произойти, если бы препятствием для него не послужило реальное действие или событие первого предложения);
   соответствует по значению словам **а то, иначе**.
2. **Употребляется при соединении предложений или членов предложения**, указывая на их противопоставление или сопоставление;
   соответствует по значению слову **иначе**.
3. **Употребляется при присоединении однородного члена предложения или однородного предложения**, подчеркивая важность последующей части высказывания; 
   соответствует по значению словам **а не то, а иначе**.
4. **Употребляется при присоединении однородного члена предложения или целого предложения** (характеризующихся чередованием действий);
   соответствует по значению словам **или же, а то**.

Всё правильно говорит *Грамота* и примеры приводит правильные.
Формулировка "синтаксические конструкции, присоединяемые союзом..." означает, что запятыми выделяется **не сам** союз, а **всё** придаточное предложение (или однородный член предложения), в которое он входит.

*Не опаздывайте к назначенному времени отправления автобуса, **в противном случае вам придется добираться до отеля самостоятельно.***

*Задание должно быть выполнено, **в противном случае будут приняты строгие меры.***

Answer (score 5):

Вот что пишет Грамота.ру:

> В ПРОТИВНОМ СЛУЧАЕ, союз
>   Синтаксические конструкции, присоединяемые союзом «в противном случае», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми.
>
> Скажите им, чтобы они не смели преследовать нас, в противном случае они будут жестоко наказаны. В. Обручев, Плутония. Самозванство – явление хроническое и отчасти даже типическое, в противном случае Гоголь не вывел бы Поприщина. Ю. Давыдов, Синие тюльпаны.
>
> @ Изредка встречается употребление слов «в противном случае» в роли членов предложения: Разбойник объявлял о своем намерении немедленно идти на нашу крепость; приглашал казаков и солдат в свою шайку, а командиров увещевал не супротивляться, угрожая казнию в противном случае. А. Пушкин, Капитанская дочка.

Обратите внимание: выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми конструкции, а не сам союз, а Вы спрашиваете, почему после **союза** запятая не ставится.

Answer (score 4):

После союза запятая не нужна: *конструкции*, о которых в том материале идёт речь, *отделяются* запятой **вместе с союзом**, то есть запятая ставится *перед* ним. В случае двустороннего *выделения* такой конструкции (когда предложение на ней не заканчивается) после неё ставится вторая запятая.

Случай же с запятой *после* "в противном случае" (*не в функции союза*) можно себе представить с этим сочетанием  в конце конструкции, которая отделена от окончания предложения по внешней причине:

> Премия будет выплачена в случае выполнения предприятием годового плана
>   и не будет выплачена *в противном случае*, поскольку так записано в
>   трудовом договоре.

Answer (score 2):

1) ***В противном случае*** ― это наречное выражение, которое используется в сложносочиненных предложениях в качестве **союза со  значением альтернативной мотивации,** это же значение могут иметь союзы **ИЛИ, А ТО, А НЕ ТО и наречие ИНАЧЕ.**

Такое предложение описывает **две альтернативные ситуации**, одна из которых оценивается как нежелательное следствие. **Запятая перед союзами этой группы ставится:**  Мои наилучшие пожелания тебе в случае, если ты скоро вернёшься домой, **в противном случае** я желаю тебе мужества, много мужества, чтобы выдержать тюремные страдания. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

2) ***В противном случае*** может стоять в начале простоо предложения, в этом случае падежная форма приобретает дополнительное присоединительное значение по отношению к контексту (запятая поле сочетания не ставится): **В противном случае банкиры** грозятся сокращением потребительского кредитования на 60%. [Дмитрий Яковенко.  2014]

3) Также сочетание может использоваться в качестве наречия, синонима наречия ***иначе***, в этом случае оно не выделяется запятыми:
Считается, что Пекин был вынужден пойти на уступки, потому что ***в противном случае*** ему пришлось бы покупать сжиженный газ у Катара по вдвое более высокой цене. [Дмитрий Карцев. 2014]